# Enumerate groups of consecutive equal values in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I'm trying to uniquely label consecutive rows with equal values in a PySpark dataframe. In Pandas, one could do this quite simply with:

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3])
s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    4
dtype: int64
```

How could this be done in PySpark? Setup -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pandasToSparkDF').getOrCreate()

mySchema = StructType([StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True)])
df_sp = spark.createDataFrame(s.to_frame(), schema=mySchema)
```

I've found slightly related questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309693/grouping-consecutive-rows-in-pyspark-dataframe), but none of them about this same scenario.

I'm thinking a good starting point could be to find the first differences as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156367/date-difference-between-consecutive-rows-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with a solution. The idea is similar to what is done in Pandas. We start by adding an unique identifier column, `over` which we'll compute the lagged column (using `over` here is necessary since it is a window function).

We then compare the column of interest with the lagged column and take the cumulative sum of the result cast to `int`:

```
mySchema = StructType([StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True)])
df_sp = spark.createDataFrame(s.to_frame(), schema=mySchema)

win = Window.orderBy("id")
df_sp = (df_sp.withColumn("id", f.monotonically_increasing_id())
              .withColumn("col1_shift", f.lag("col1", offset=1, default=0).over(win))
              .withColumn("col1_shift_ne", (f.col("col1") != f.col("col1_shift")).cast("int"))
              .withColumn("col1_shift_ne_cumsum", f.sum("col1_shift_ne").over(win))
              .drop(*['id','col1_shift', 'col1_shift_ne']))

df_sp.show()
---+--------------------+
|col1|col1_shift_ne_cumsum|
+----+--------------------+
|   1|                   1|
|   1|                   1|
|   1|                   1|
|   2|                   2|
|   2|                   2|
|   1|                   3|
|   1|                   3|
|   3|                   4|
+----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving this would be using a rangebetween and using unbounded preceeding sum after comparing the lag:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

w1 = W.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())
w2 = W.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id()).rangeBetween(W.unboundedPreceding,0)

cond = F.col("col1") != F.lag("col1").over(w1)
df_sp.withColumn("col1_shift_ne_cumsum",F.sum(F.when(cond,1).otherwise(0)).over(w2)+1).show()
```

---

```
+----+--------------------+
|col1|col1_shift_ne_cumsum|
+----+--------------------+
|   1|                   1|
|   1|                   1|
|   1|                   1|
|   2|                   2|
|   2|                   2|
|   1|                   3|
|   1|                   3|
|   3|                   4|
+----+--------------------+
```